# Basic standalone horizontal menu

Tags: html, css

Here is what I'm starting with. It is just some `<p>` tags in a `<div>` tag.

```
   <div id='mi_control' class='radius_all'>
      <p id='mi_cover_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Arcmarks &copy; </p>
      <p id='mi_about_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>About</p>
      <p id='mi_privacy_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Privacy</p>
      <p id='mi_team_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Contact</p>
      <p id='mi_arc_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Developers</p>
    </div>
```

This [post seems a bit unrelated](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44085/horizontal-menu-for-3-items) as I just want to know the HTML/CSS structure for a horizontal menu.

Here is what it looks like and what I want it to look like:

[image: footer]

Comment: Is the first entry ("Arcmarks" + copyright) supposed to be a link, too?

Comment: This question has been [mentioned on Meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6778/9357).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on personal experience as well as [this blog post](http://css-snippets.com/simple-horizontal-navigation/), I'd recommend that you use an unordered list `ul` versus `div` and `p`, because it's a more accurate representation of the actual content you're marking up (semantic markup).

Here's a modified (`div` replaced with `nav`) snippet of the HTML from the article I linked to above:

```
<nav class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="tutorials"><a class="active" href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
    <li class="about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="news"><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
    <li class="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

For the CSS to create a horizontal list, you could either use `display: inline-block;` or `float: left;` on the `li` items. If you need to support older browsers, like IE7, then you'll most likely want to use `float`. For more information on how to decide which technique to use, I'd take a look at [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805352/floatleft-vs-displayinline-vs-displayinline-block-vs-displaytable-cell).

Comment: +1 for the `ul`, but a div isn't really appropriate. `nav` is the semantically correct element.

Comment: Why did you wrap the `<ul>` tag in any tag? - whether `<div>` or `<nav>`

Comment: @cadegalt Good practice. A `div` doesn't say much about the contained content, but `nav` does. "The HTML Navigation Element (<nav>) represents a section of a page that links to other pages or to parts within the page: a section with navigation links." - [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav)

Comment: It also makes it easier to apply styling to the section. You may have other uls that you want to style differently.

Comment: @Lauren - I didn't mean a `<nav>` specifically, I meant in general why wrap it in a tag at all?

Comment: @cadegalt It's not necessary to wrap it in a tag. It's just good practice to use semantic markup, like a `nav` element, in this instance. It's helpful for anything that's analyzing your markup, for example search engines, browsers or screenreaders (per [HTML5Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/), which Phrancis' answer referenced).

Comment: `<nav>` seems to be the only consensus as a semantically correct element.  I'm going to go with divs for the items themselves as did Phrancis below.

Comment: @cadegalt - A `<nav>` element has a built-in ARIA role that, among other things, carries a known user-agent behaviour (with different behaviours for different user-agents, of course). It doesn't take a lot of effort to make a site/page accessible at that level, and designing for accessibility is, as often as not, a matter of applying appropriate semantics rather than taking any heroic measures. And never forget that "accessibility" and "good SEO practices" are pretty much synonyms; if you can make a screen reader or a Braille terminal happy, you can make Google or Bing ecstatic.

Comment: @Stan - finally someone with something to say - now I won't feel like I'm blindly following convention or being "semantically correct" - functionality is key for me - Thanks.

Comment: @cadegalt I'm not sure why your last comment was necessary. Stan simply expanded, with helpful information, on what I had already summarized: "It's helpful for anything that's analyzing your markup, for example search engines, browsers or screenreaders". I spent time carefully crafting both the answer and my replies to you with the intention of being helpful to another. Maybe I'm simply misperceiving your comment but, to me, it has a certain tone and implies some things that I find it a bit hard to take after spending time trying to be helpful.

Comment: I up-voted your answer and marked it. It was helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: @Lauren, or other devs, including yourself a few months down the line - I like `<nav>` as they can then take layout styles without being wrapped in another div, which is semantic and succinct

Comment: @cadegalt - the point of semantics is that by having well defined, strong semantics, you can then hook in lots more functionality, even if the funcitonality isn't immediately apparent or obvious - it's much easier for example, for tech to find a standardised `<nav>` tag and treat it as navigation than it is to find a div that could have any arbitrary way of identifying itself as nav

Answer (score 5):

Hmm, when it comes to horizontal lists, there's not really a *standard* best-way-to-do-it, you've just gotta see which works best for your solution.

`<div>`s are one option, even replacing your `<p>` tags with `<div>`s.

Or, on the other hand, you could try a `<ul>`.

---

A `<ul>` is specifically for un-ordered lists, which seems to best fit the context of what you have.

They have a structure like:

```
<ul>
    <li>First Item</li>
    <li>Second Item</li>
</ul>
```

A vanilla `<ul>` is tagged with a bullet, but, you can use style elements of `list-style: none` on the `<ul>` and `display: inline` on the `<li>` to make it appear in a row.

```
.footer {
    list-style: none;
}
.footer li {
    display: inline;
}
```

---

Rather than attaching `class='menu_bottom small_dark'` to all of the elements, you can just write the CSS so that it puts that style on all children elements of the parent tag, and if you have certain elements that don't want to have that, you can just add `:not(.escape)` to the CSS and escape it.

Answer (score 5):

You are using paragraph `<p>` markers for what is really just a word or very short link. Semantically, you should try to use HTML tags that best represent the element you are wanting to make. So I would use `<p>` for actal text paragraphs only.

In your case, what I think would make the most sense, semantically, would be to use [`<nav>`](http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/) elements to group together your navigation menu. You could also always use `<div>` which is the most generic element possible, although it is usually preferable to use something that represents better what the element is.

Some links:

- [`nav` element on HTML5Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/)
- [`nav` documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav)
- [HTML5 sectionining elements](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_HTML5_section_elements) (for reference of other very useful semantic sectioning elements)

One example way to do this (there are others, as mentioned by others):

```
   <nav id='mi_control' class='radius_all'>
      <div id='mi_cover_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Arcmarks &copy; </div>
      <div id='mi_about_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>About</div>
      <div id='mi_privacy_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Privacy</div>
      <div id='mi_team_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Contact</div>
      <div id='mi_arc_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Developers</div>
    </nav>
```

---

One note, on using separate `id`s for each item: Unless you plan on each item to be uniquely different (and even that might not be a good use case), use classes instead of IDs.

Comment: Beat me to it. `nav` is the right element to use here.

Comment: So much opinion in web development - I've heard `<p>` , `<div>`, and `<nav>`, and `<li>` I don't think it matters.   There is no semantically correct element, if there was it would be called menu item `<mi>`.  That seems to be the concept to grasp - use a semantically useful tag if it exists, otherwise use a generic tag.

Comment: Thats not true @cadegalt. `nav` is the semantically correct element to use for a navigation section.

Comment: I thought it was obvious that I was referring to each individual menu item.  Are you suggesting that I use `<nav>` for each menu item?

Comment: Let me revise my answer a bit to clarify usage